# Shared folders not appearing in media in Ubuntu guest on Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 guest running on Windows 10.  When I add a shared folder to Oracle Virtual Box I don't see any errors appear, but I'm not seeing anything appear in my /media folder.  I'm running a `tail /var/log/syslog -f` and nothing is showing up there either.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the [VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-a-gui-less-ubuntu-server-host/) for shared folders to work. After this is done, you need to add yourself to the `vboxsf` group.

```
sudo adduser <username> vboxsf
```

Log out, log back in, and you should see your shared folder under `/media`.

Comment: sure but I cant access it, error .... permission denied